# How to add favicons while editing an HTML document? (for school project)

Tags: html, favicon

I have been trying to add a favicon to my webpage for a 9th grade school project. I am using Coda 2. I haven't acquired a domain and the webpage isn't hosted online. I've read that one could upload the image URL to their root directory or something along those lines however I can't do so in my situation. Is it possible to add a favicon on my HTML document if I view it on Google Chrome? If yes, what's the code to do so?

I have used the code below however it doesn't seem to work. I have also converted it to png and changed the 'type' but that too doesn't work. I've already made sure that the HTML document and image file are in the same folder.

```
<link rel='shortcut icon' href="favicon.ico" type='image/x-icon'/>
```

Comment: You changed the type, but I don't know what that means? You need to include more details as to what you did

Answer (score 1):

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a **favicon** and **shortcut icon** like this.

```
<head>
<!-- head content -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png" sizes="32x32"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png" sizes="32x32"/>
<!-- head content -->
</head>
```

That it =)